# Angular Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularCharts due to: Error: [$injector:nomod]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

This question has been asked many times but in my case the usual answers were not helpful so posting it. I am hoping the code below followed by the error should be self explanatory

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module yoangfull2App due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularCharts due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angularCharts' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

HTML:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-charts/dist/angular-charts.js"></script>
```

Javascript: 
    'use strict';

```
angular.module('yoangfull2App', ['angularCharts'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/archives', {
        templateUrl: 'app/archives/archives.html',
        controller: 'ArchivesCtrl'
      });
  });
```

Comment: are you using the latest version of angular charts?

Comment: Is your angular code in its own js file? Where is you reference to that?

Comment: can you please create jsFiddle?

Comment: @Melbourne2991 I did a bower install. Should be latest ?

Comment: @haxtbh Do you mean the controller when you say angular code ? If yes then yeah its in a different file. The problem happens the moment I add ['angularCharts']

Comment: @Shreejibawa It's a big project . I will try but not sure how much I would be able to replicate.

Comment: Yes, but where is the reference to that file, in relation to all of your other script tags. Your controller js should be loaded last after all of the bower components.

Comment: @haxtbh It's after/below the above script tags. Didn't include that to reduce the size of the post

Comment: Always include relevant things, otherwise people are just going to end up asking questions that dont need to be asked. Try manually downloading angular-charts and including it to eliminate bower problems.

Comment: @haxbh bang on the money. The error changes to 

    Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module yoangfull2App due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider

Comment: to fix that error you need to include angular-route it comes separate to the angular core. 

Then `angular.module('yoangfull2App', ['angularCharts', 'ngRoute'])`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple angular charts library are available. first check which one your are using and add that dependency in your project.
like if you are using

http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

the charts.js is the dependency name or if you are using

http://chinmaymk.github.io/angular-charts/

and you installed it using bower then add it in same order as suggested there:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='./bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='./bower_components/d3/d3.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='./bower_components/angular-charts/dist/angular-charts.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using [angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)? If you do, the dependency is `chart.js`, not `angularCharts`.

Check the module name in your angular-charts.js file. check the dependency name.